# Automating Opening Transcript for Youtube Automatic Generated Captions

Tags: python, selenium, youtube, automation

I am trying to write a python script that will automate the clicking of opening the transcript for a youtube video.

For example, if you go to a youtube video, two to the right of the share button(represented by the 3 dots), you can open up the transcript of the youtube video.

The code I have so far opens the URL, and turns on the closed caption(which works).

```
from selenium import webdriver
import requests

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q1RYI034sH0")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "ytp-subtitles-button")))
element.click()
```

However, I know want to open the transcript by adding the following-code, which produces an error because it cannot locate the button.

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "yt-icon-button)")))
```

I am not really sure what to do from here, and any help to automate opening youtube's transcript is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this code:

```
# opens 'More actions' menu
more_action_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label = 'More actions']")))
more_action_btn.click()

# clicks on 'open transcription' button    
open_trancript_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//paper-listbox[@id = 'items']/ytd-menu-service-item-renderer")))
open_trancript_btn.click()
```

Comment: The first action works perfectly, it clicks the more actions button(Thank you!). However, the second command gives an error "Timeout.Exception" because the Xpath is incorrect. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, I did a mistake with second element, please check the updated answer

Comment: Was trying to make this work. Seems to be broken:   File "scrape-videos-for-stations.py", line 32, in get_transcript
    more_action_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@aria-label = 'More actions']")))
  File "C:\Users\Roman Davis\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)